# Sort files then directories os.listdir PYTHON

Tags: python, sorting, directory, alphabetical, listdir

I'm trying to sort files and directories in specific way (for me it is usuall way but ok). So I have JPG files, then some txt files or wav and I have some directories I want it sorted like first sort by name all files then sort directories but when I'm trying to do something like :

```
path = "/my_path"
arr = os.listdir(path)
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (os.path.isdir(x), x))
print(arr)
```

Code gives me output :

```
['10000100.JPG', '10000101.JPG', '10000102.JPG', '10000103.JPG', '10000104.BMP', 'BACKUP.BIN', 'DEPOSIT.BIN', 'HRYS', 'WAVS', 'k.txt', 's.wav']
```

but it should be :

```
['10000100.JPG', '10000101.JPG', '10000102.JPG', '10000103.JPG', '10000104.BMP', 'BACKUP.BIN', 'DEPOSIT.BIN', 'k.txt', 's.wav', 'HRYS', 'WAVS']
```

How to do it in proper way ?

Comment: can you `print([(os.path.isdir(x), x) for x in arr])`

Comment: `[(False, '10000100.JPG'), (False, '10000101.JPG'), (False, '10000102.JPG'), (False, '10000103.JPG'), (False, '10000104.BMP'),  (False, 'BACKUP.BIN'), (False, 'DEPOSIT.BIN'), (False, 'HRYS'), (False, 'WAVS'), (False, 'k.txt'), (False, 's.wav')]`

Comment: Well then, it seems that `'HRYS'` and `'WAVS'` are *not directories*.

Comment: but they are :) as u can see there is no  '.'

Comment: Why do you think that is in any way relevant? Try `with open('noperiod') as f: f.write('see! no period!')` and you'll see that you have created a file without a `'.'` in it's name...

Comment: okok it's not relevant but I can go inside this for example HRYS directory so it have to be

Comment: Aha! I see, wrong working directory. Check my edit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the most straightforward way is to provide an appropriate `key`, so, you can use:

```
arr.sort(key=lambda x: (os.path.isdir(x), x))
```

The key is a tuple, the first item is `os.path.isdir(x)`, which returns a `bool`.

EDIT: So, to make *sure* this works, do:

```
def isdir(path, x):
    path = os.path.join(path, x)
    return os.path.isdir(path)

arr.sort(key=lambda x: (isdir(path, x), x))
```

Although, it might be easier to use `os.scandir`, which returns more useful `DirEntry` objects.

```
arr = sorted(os.scandir(), key=lambda x: (x.is_dir(), x.name))
```

Comment: I use this line but I get same output as before

Comment: @BengBeng can you show your actual output and the exact code you are using?

Comment: now it works :) I came up with same idea that os.path.isdir wont work but you were faster ! :)

Comment: just instead of `return os.isdir(path)` put `return os.path.isdir(path)` :)

Comment: @BengBeng yeah, I suggest using `os.scandir` instead anyways.